# How to reduce jre size for bundling with an application ?

Tags: java, size, reduce

I want to reduce size of jre. Already I have exclude some files from jre which are given bellow.

```
bin\java.exe
bin\javaw.exe
bin\javaws.exe
bin\javacpl.exe
bin\jucheck.exe
bin\dtplugin
bin\jabswitch.exe
bin\java_crw_demo.dll
bin\JavaAccessBridge-32.dll
bin\JavaAccessBridge.dll
bin\JAWTAccessBridge-32.dll
bin\JAWTAccessBridge.dll
bin\WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll
bin\WindowsAccessBridge.dll
bin\wsdetect.dll
bin\dtplugin\*
bin\plugin2\*
bin\deploy.dll
bin\jfr.dll
bin\javacpl.cpl
lib\deploy.jar
lib\plugin.jar
lib\deploy\*
lib/jfxswt.jar
bin\decora-sse.dll
bin\fxplugins.dll
bin\glass.dll
bin\glib-lite.dll
bin\gstreamer-lite.dll
bin\javafx-font.dll
bin\javafx_font_t2k.dll
bin\javafx-iio.dll
bin\jfxmedia.dll
bin\jfxwebkit.dll
bin\prism_common.dll
bin\prism-d3d.dll
bin\prism_es2.dll
bin\prism_sw.dll
```

After excluding this files it's size is 107 mb. But I need to make jre size within 60 mb or 70 mb for my application, Main part of my application are also given bellow.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    try {
        //LOGGER.info("Application started");
        Server server = new Server(8680);

        //LOGGER.info("Application started1");
        ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(servletHandler);

        //LOGGER.info("Application started2");
        servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        LOGGER.info(" " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Default jre size is 170 mb. But I need just 60 mb or 70 mb size of jre for this application.
Now what can I do to make size of jre is 60 mb or 70 mb.

Comment: Why not use Java 9+ and `jlink`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I use Java 9+ then could I reduce jre size.

Comment: Check the docs of the JLink utility, which allows you to package just the required modules

Comment: This will be a tough job with Java 8 - `rt.jar` itself is about 60 Mb

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Javafx then it'd help to delete the "bin\jfxwebkit.dll" file as it's more than 50 MBs.